# System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

Tags: c#

I have installed System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe version 6.0.0 (nuget package manager) in my application/spec projects. Also manually updated  following bindingredirect in my app.config file.

But still getting below error. Note that all my spec projects are working fine in local system but fails with below error while running through team city.

System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
----> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: What dotnet version is your project targeting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Project target framework is 4.7.1